# pgAdmin 4 overlay would not close

Tags: pgadmin-4

This is a weird one. I just installed PostgresSQL 12 on my computer. When I fire up pgAdmin, I'm presented with a blank overlay. There is no close button anywhere. I can move it around, but not close it.
What is this overlay, and how can I close it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try running reset layout?

Goto File (menu) -> Reset Layout

Comment: I think that did it. Thank you.